# Capture a AWS lambda function's output and email it via SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, serverless, amazon-sns

Lambda function code:

```
import json
import datetime
import redshift_module.pygresql_redshift_common as db_handler
from decouple import config
import pg

host = config('host')
port = config('port')
db_name = config('db_name')
db_user = config('db_user')
db_password = config('db_password')


def get_connection(host, port, dbname, user, password):
    rs_conn_string = "host=%s port=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s" % (
        host, port, dbname, user, password)
    rs_conn = pg.connect(dbname=rs_conn_string)
    rs_conn.query("set statement_timeout = 1200000")
    return rs_conn


def query(con, query):
    res = con.query(query)
    return res


rs_conn = db_handler.get_connection(host, port, db_name, db_user, db_password)
query_string = "call XYZ_warehouse.ABC_revenue_last_7_days();"

res = query(rs_conn, query_string)
print(res.getresults())


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')}
```

So the code runs a query function on a redshift database.
The output of the lambda contains strings like following:

```
DEUS revenue is completely matching and revenue is : 5139 and Revenue without shipping is: 4987
```

What i need to do is capture lines like these in the execution results, maybe store them in a variable or in a log file somewhere so i can then email them. Ive tried running `.getresults()` on the query object but it returns an empty string. Maybe because its not returning a record or a table?

Is there a way i can capture the complete output of a lambda function? or send it to a file somewhere?

Comment: Posted a solutions which talks about lambda destinations, i think it should suit your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary and save all output you want to send via email.

Now convert it to json and send via SNS or SES

Comment: i actually need to know how to access the output (Execution Results) of the lambda?
The query code that runs has no attribute for results or response.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, do you also want help with retrieving your query results?

If so I suggest you read from [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift-data.html)

> Is there a way i can capture the complete output of a lambda function? or send it to a file somewhere?

One option is to send the output of your lambda func to an s3 bucket e.g.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id=KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_KEY
)
content="String content to write to a new S3 file"
s3.Object('my-bucket-name', 'newfile.txt').put(Body=content)
```

you can set up an s3 trigger that will then [trigger a second lambda as soon as a new object is added to the bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html).

Your second lambda can then transform to JSON and send via SNS/SES as Vaquar Khan's answer.

Comment: Here the code is defining the `content` and then sending it, but how can i capture the output of the lambda in a variable? coz there is no attribute or method in the code that can get the result of the query.

Comment: You have quite a few options here from the other answers. However your question is very unclear. 

is `res = query(rs_conn, query_string)` not returning the results you want?

Comment: yes, the res is `None` after execution, becuase the guy who made these queries said they are sort of functions running on the db, not traditional queries. The whole reason why i have to resort to cloudwatch logs...

Comment: @BUCKSHOT I suggest you edit your original question to make that clear.

Also your coworker has copied from step 5 here so you may find that helpful https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly " you want to store output of lambda in separate place/file" to use it as email.

If it is a pure lambda output you can simple use **lambda destinations**.

Destinations allows you to segregate results based on failure or success. if it is success you can send it to a target ( SNS, SQS, EventBridge or different Lambda), if it is failure you can send it to failure destination

[Destinations docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved

The solution I figured out as a beginner is:

- Create another lambda function that is triggered with CloudwatchLogs.
- Choose the log group of the function that is outputting the query result. Its logs will have the lines you need.
- To get those lines from the logs you need this code:

  - ```
    decoded_data = json.loads(gzip.decompress(b64decode(event['awslogs']['data'])))
    ```
  - The latest log created from your query lambda function will be stored in `decoded_data`
  - Then extract the line you want from the dictionary and email it via SNS.